# Does the Unary Operators(++ or --) are allowed in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, operator-keyword

From the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_operators.htm it is clear that e ++ and -- are not valid vb.net operators.

Why the following snippet will not **showing error or exception**?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a, b, c, d As Integer
    a = 5
    b = 10
    c = ++b + a
    MsgBox(c) ' display 15
    d = b + ++a
    MsgBox(d) ' display 15
End Sub
```

How the values are calculated to show the result as 15?
why the compiler does not give error?

Comment: From what I'm seeing, it ignores the `++`... But that's a pretty good question!

Comment: @silentw : that means vb.net will support `++`?

Comment: VB is not ignoring it - every '+' operator used this way is just assumed to mean "positive" and every '-' operator used this way is just assumed to mean "negative". If you want to use 10 of them together VB has no problem with that, but it's just "positive" and "negative", nothing more.

Comment: You can understand the behavior more if you try this "a = ---b"